# Can i declare and initialize ImageView outside for and swtich statement and set its property withing them?

Tags: java, javafx

This code is working (ImageView is decared globally but initializing and setting its property in the for and switch statement)

```
private static ImageView imgP;
public static Pane board = new Pane();

public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
    Rectangle r1,r;
    for(int i = 0;i<64;i+=2) {
        r = new Rectangle((i%8 + (i/8)%2)*tileSize,(i/8)*tileSize, tileSize,tileSize);
        r.setFill(Color.rgb(255,200,100));
        r1 = new Rectangle(((i+1)%8-(((i+1)/8)%2))*tileSize,(((i+1))/8)*tileSize,tileSize,tileSize);
        r1.setFill(Color.rgb(150,50,30));

        board.getChildren().addAll(r,r1);
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<64;i++) {
        switch(Test.board[i/8][i%8]) {
        case "P":
                imgP = new ImageView(new Image("images/11.png"));
                imgP.setFitWidth(tileSize);
                imgP.setFitHeight(tileSize);
                imgP.setX((i%8 )*tileSize);
                imgP.setY((i/8)*tileSize);
                board.getChildren().add(imgP);
            break;
         }
     }
     Scene scene = new Scene(board);
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

This code does not (ImageView is decared globally and initialized outside for and switch statement while setting its property aftewards)

```
private static ImageView imgP;
public static Pane board = new Pane();

public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
    Rectangle r1,r;
    ImageView imgP = new ImageView(new Image("images/11.png"));
    for(int i = 0;i<64;i+=2) {
        r = new Rectangle((i%8 + (i/8)%2)*tileSize,(i/8)*tileSize, tileSize,tileSize);
        r.setFill(Color.rgb(255,200,100));
        r1 = new Rectangle(((i+1)%8-(((i+1)/8)%2))*tileSize,(((i+1))/8)*tileSize,tileSize,tileSize);
        r1.setFill(Color.rgb(150,50,30));

        board.getChildren().addAll(r,r1);
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<64;i++) {
        switch(Test.board[i/8][i%8]) {
        case "P":
                imgP.setFitWidth(tileSize);
                imgP.setFitHeight(tileSize);
                imgP.setX((i%8 )*tileSize);
                imgP.setY((i/8)*tileSize);
                board.getChildren().add(imgP);
            break;
        }
       }
       Scene scene = new Scene(board);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

The error is generated is as follows:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Pane@5a3b6136
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at FrontEnd.start(FrontEnd.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
```

Please explain with reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaFX a `Node` cannot be added to the same parent more than once at the same time. That's why you're getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Pane@5a3b6136
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:454)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at FrontEnd.start(FrontEnd.java:47)
    // Omitted rest of stack trace for brevity...
```

In your code you call `board.getChildren().add(imgP)` *each* iteration of the `for` loop. The problem in the second example is `imgP` is the *same instance* each time. In the first example you create a new instance each iteration.

If your goal is to avoid creating multiple `Image`s of the same thing then what you should be doing is sharing the same `Image` instance between multiple `ImageView`s.

Comment: even if i remove for loop and replace variable i with 51 still gives the same problem (exception in application start method).My motive is to have references for each instance of ImageView and use them to add and remove the images from the pane

Comment: "_exception in application start method_" is not necessarily the same error. Is it still an `IllegalArgumentException` with the same message? Is the same code (i.e. line) throwing the error?

Comment: it comes every time i try to initialize image view out of switch body and setting its property and adding to pane inside switch error is same as above error except duplicate children added